# Create nested json from parsed textinput

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing, recursion

I'm trying to create a javascript function to parse text to nested JSON but I'm stuck at managing it recursive.

So basically convert what's in textbox:

```
todo list
  learn js
     hello world
shopping list
  costco
procrastination list
```

to this:

```
[
{'val':'todo list','children':[{'val':'learn js','children':['val':'hello world']}]},
{'val':'shopping list','children':[{'val':'costco'}]},
{'val':'procrastination list'}
]
```

I've come up with this:

```
const TxtParser = txtBoxVal => {
  let txtArr = [];
  let nbrSpacesPrev = 0;
  if (txtBoxVal) {
    if (txtBoxVal.split("\n").length) {
      let lines = txtBoxVal.split("\n");
      let numNewLines = txtBoxVal.split("\n").length;
      let i;
      for (i = 0; i < numNewLines; i++) {
        if (lines[i].search(/\S/) !== -1) {
          let txtObj = {};
          txtObj["line"] = lines[i].trim();
          // check for space diff
          txtObj["nbrSpaces"] = lines[i].search(/\S/);
          txtArr.push(txtObj);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return txtArr;
};
```

I only get linear results:
https://codesandbox.io/s/text-to-json-parser-kuc28

I can't wrap my head around on how to create nested children.

Comment: are the number of spaces always in the same format?

Comment: As long as it's more nested than before, just like simplified version of yaml

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if you can work with this already. Else I can write you the insert function into your Object as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**recursive approach**

You have a super fun problem! I'm going to add a few more elements to your  input so we can see that siblings and descendants are nesting properly. I also scattered in some empty lines to make our program more robust -

```js
const data = `
todo list
  learn js
    hello world
    functions

shopping list
  costco
  berries


  mushrooms
procrastination list
`
```

To begin, we will `sanitize` the data by removing any empty lines, and all leading and trailing white space -

```js
const sanitize = (str = "") =>
  str.trim().replace(/\n\s*\n/g, "\n")

console.log(sanitize(data))
```

```
todo list
  learn js
    hello world
    functions
shopping list
  costco
  berries
  mushrooms
procrastination list
```

With a clean starting point, we can begin breaking the problem down...

---

**design**

Let's substitute spaces for `•` and line endings for `¬` so we can see what's going on. We begin by calling `makeChildren` on the clean string -

```
makeChildren(
  todo•list¬
  ••learn•js¬
  ••••hello•world¬
  ••••functions¬
  shopping•list¬
  ••costco¬
  ••berries¬
  ••mushrooms¬
  procrastination•list
)
```

`makeChildren` creates an array and calls `make1` on each element -

```
[ make1(
    todo•list¬
    ••learn•js¬
    ••••hello•world¬
    ••••functions¬
  )
, make1(
    shopping•list¬
    ••costco¬
    ••berries¬
    ••mushrooms¬
  )
, make1(
    procrastination•list
  )
]
```

`make1` creates a node and subsequently calls `makeChildren` on its descendants -

```
[ { value: todo•list
  , children: makeChildren(outdent(
      ••learn•js¬
      ••••hello•world¬
      ••••functions¬
    ))
  }
, { value: shopping•list
  , children: makeChildren(outdent(
      ••costco¬
      ••berries¬
      ••mushrooms¬
    ))
  }
, { value: procrastination•list
  , children: makeChildren(outdent(

    ))
  }
]
```

And as we already saw, `makeChildren` creates an array and calls `make1` on each child -

```
[ { value: todo•list
  , children:
      [ make1(
          learn•js¬
          ••hello•world¬
          ••functions¬
        )
      ]
  }
, { value: shopping•list
  , children:
      [ make1(costco¬)
      , make1(berries¬)
      , make1(mushrooms¬)
      ]
  }
, { value: procrastination•list
  , children:
      []
  }
]
```

And on-and-on the [mutually recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) process continues... `makeChildren` calls `make1` which calls `makeChildren` which calls `make1` etc, until the base case is met in each branch.

---

**implement**

Per our design, we will start with `makeChildren` -

```
const makeChildren = (str = "") =>
  str === ""
    ? []
    : str.split(/\n(?!\s)/).map(make1)
```

Which asks us to implement `make1` -

```js
const make1 = (str = "") =>
{ const [ value, children ] = cut(str, "\n")
  return { value, children: makeChildren(outdent(children)) }
}
```

Which asks us to implement `cut` and `outdent` -

- `cut` works like `String.prototype.split` but only splits `str` on the *first* occurrence of `char`
- `outdent` removes *one* level of indenting

```js
const cut = (str = "", char = "") =>
{ const pos = str.search(char)
  return pos === -1
    ? [ str, "" ]
    : [ str.substr(0, pos), str.substr(pos + 1) ]
}

const outdent = (str = "") =>
{ const spaces = Math.max(0, str.search(/\S/))
  const re = new RegExp(`(^|\n)\\s{${spaces}}`, "g")
  return str.replace(re, "$1")
}
```

And that's it! The final `result` is -

```js
const result =
  makeChildren(sanitize(data))

console.log(result)
```

```js
[ { value: "todo list"
  , children:
      [ { value: "learn js"
        , children:
            [ { value: "hello world", children: [] }
            , { value: "functions", children: [] }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
, { value: "shopping list"
  , children:
      [ { value: "costco", children: [] }
      , { value: "berries", children: [] }
      , { value: "mushrooms", children: [] }
      ]
  }
, { value: "procrastination list", children: [] }
]
```

Run the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const sanitize = (str = "") =>
  str.trim().replace(/\n\s*\n/g, "\n")

const cut = (str = "", char = "") =>
{ const pos = str.search(char)
  return pos === -1
    ? [ str, "" ]
    : [ str.substr(0, pos), str.substr(pos + 1) ]
}

const outdent = (str = "") =>
{ const spaces = Math.max(0, str.search(/\S/))
  const re = new RegExp(`(^|\n)\\s{${spaces}}`, "g")
  return str.replace(re, "$1")
}

const makeChildren = (str) =>
  str === ""
    ? []
    : str.split(/\n(?!\s)/).map(make1)

const make1 = (str = "") =>
{ const [ value, children ] = cut(str, "\n")
  return { value, children: makeChildren(outdent(children)) }
}

const data = `
todo list
  learn js
    hello world
    functions

shopping list
  costco
  berries


  mushrooms
procrastination list
`

const result =
  makeChildren(sanitize(data))

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
// [ { value: "todo list"
//   , children:
//       [ { value: "learn js"
//         , children:
//             [ { value: "hello world", children: [] }
//             , { value: "functions", children: [] }
//             ]
//         }
//       ]
//   }
// , { value: "shopping list"
//   , children:
//       [ { value: "costco", children: [] }
//       , { value: "berries", children: [] }
//       , { value: "mushrooms", children: [] }
//       ]
//   }
// , { value: "procrastination list", children: [] }
// ]
```

---

**makes sense to me!**

Is a program "simple and straightforward" because it makes sense to me? What if we could use *objective* qualities to make such assertions? @tokafew420 is confident with their program, and so I offer this objective analysis.

I changed variable names to `_n` in **each** program so we can easily identify and count the individual moving parts -

```js
const TxtParser = _1 => { // 10 total variables; 4 mutations; 5 variable reassignments
  let _2 = []; // <-- mutates below but never reassigned; should be const
  let _3 = []; // <-- mutates below but never reassigned; should be const
  let _4 = {   // <-- reassigned below
    nbrSpaces: -1,
    children: _2 // <-- mutates below
  };
  let _5; // <-- reassigned below
  if (_1) {
    let _6 = _1.split("\n"); // <-- reassignment #1
    let _7 = _6.length;      // <-- reassignment #2
    if (_7) {
      let i;                 // <-- mutates; leaks variable out of `for` scope
      for (i = 0; i < _7; i++) {     // <-- mutation #1
        let _8 = _6[i].trim();       // <-- never reassigned, does not mutate; should be const
        let _9 = _6[i].search(/\S/); // <-- never reassigned, does not mutate; should be const
        if (_8) {
          let _10 = {                // <-- never reassigned, does not mutate; should be const
            line: _8,
            nbrSpaces: _9,
            children: []
          };
          if (_5 && _9 > _5.nbrSpaces) {
            _3.push(_4);         // <-- mutation #2
            _4 = _5;             // <-- reassignment #3
          } else {
            while (_9 <= _4.nbrSpaces) {
              _4 = _3.pop();     // <-- reassignment #4 AND mutation #3
            }
          }
          _4.children.push(_10); // <-- mutation #4
          _5 = _10;              // <-- reassignment #5
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return _2;
};
```

- highest variable count in single scope: 10
- mutations: 4
- variable reassignments: 5
- lines of implementation: 36
- reusable functions: 0
- needs additional transformation to yield desired result: yes

Compare that to the declarative functional approach -

```js
const sanitize = (_1 = "") => // 1 total variable; never mutates; never reassigned
  _1.trim().replace(/\n\s*\n/g, "\n")

const cut = (_1 = "", _2 = "") => // 3 total variables; never mutates; never reassigned
{ const _3 = _1.search(_2)
  return _3 === -1
    ? [ _1, "" ]
    : [ _1.substr(0, _3), _1.substr(_3 + 1) ]
}

const outdent = (_1 = "") => // 3 total variables; never mutates; never reassigned
{ const _2 = Math.max(0, _1.search(/\S/))
  const _3 = new RegExp(`(^|\n)\\s{${_2}}`, "g")
  return _1.replace(_3, "$1")
}

const makeChildren = (_1) => // 1 total variable; never mutates; never reassigned
  _1 === ""
    ? []
    : _1.split(/\n(?!\s)/).map(make1)

const make1 = (_1 = "") =>  // 3 total variables; never mutates; never reassigned
{ const [ _2, _3 ] = cut(_1, "\n")
  return { value: _2, children: makeChildren(outdent(_3)) }
}
```

- highest variable count in single scope: 3
- mutations: 0
- variable reassignments: 0
- lines of implementation: 13
- reusable functions: 3 (`sanitize`, `cut`, `outdent`)
- needs additional transformation to yield desired result: no

**why do these things matter?**

When there's 10 variables in a single scope, and they can all change and be reassigned at any time, it's *very* difficult for our brains to keep track of all the moving pieces. This program is big and difficult to write. Even if we arrive at a correct result for one input, how do we know that our program is correct for other inputs? More tests need to be written to ensure proper behaviour and due to it's 36-lines of specific behaviour, it cannot be reused in other parts of the program.

When you compare that to the low complexity of the functional program, we have smaller functions, with well-defined purpose that are easy to write, test and maintain, and reuse in other parts of our program. As you can see, renaming the vars to `_1`, `_2`, and `_3` barely hurts readability as its easy for our brains to keep track of 3 things at once, and even easier when we know those 3 things are not mutated or reassigned.

What is the value of `x` on line `Y` of the imperative program? Due to all of the mutation and reassignment in a `for`-`while` nested loop, it's anyone's guess. Unless your brain is substituted with a computer, this question is difficult to answer for almost *all* variables and *all* lines in this program, and so I pose it is anything but simple or straightforward.

On the other hand, it's easy to answer these questions about the functional program. We can instantly know the value of any variable on any line without referencing countless other variables or incurring unmanageable conceptual overhead. If that's not simple or straightforward, I don't know what is...

/2cents

Comment: thank you for the explanation also, removing empty children result would be perfect

Comment: Although I originally started down this line, I didn't come up with the crucial `outdent`.  That makes this another elegant solution!

Comment: @Ardhi, I would suggest that you keep the nodes uniform, meaning every node will have a `children` array property. The downstream benefits of this are big because all node consumers can rely on a _known_, _dependable_ set of data. That said, it's your program so you can change how you see fit. The `return { value, children: makeChildren(outdent(children)) }` can be updated to `const newChildren = makeChildren(outdent(children)); return newChildren.length ? { value, children: newChildren } : { value };`

Answer (score 3):

(**Edit**: added the `.filter` line to sanitize the input, and switched to the input data from Thankyou to demonstrate it.)

---

Here's one approach.  We convert to an intermediate format that looks like the following:

```js
[
    {indent: 0, val: "todo list"},
    {indent: 2, val: "learn js"},
    {indent: 5, val: "hello world"},
    {indent: 0, val: "shopping list"},
    {indent: 2, val: "costco"},
    {indent: 0, val: "procrastination list"}
]
```

where the `indent`s count the spaces before the text on each line.  Then, by keeping a stack of parents of our most recent node, searching for the first one with a lower indent value than our current node, and adding the current node as one of its children, we fold that list into a data structure like this:

```js
{
    indent: -1,
    children: [
        {
            indent: 0,
            val: "todo list",
            children: [
                {indent: 2, val: "learn js", children: [{indent: 5, val: "hello world"}]}
            ],
        },
        {indent: 0, val: "shopping list" children: [{indent: 2, val: "costco"]},
        {indent: 0, val: "procrastination list"}
    ],
}
```

And finally we recurse through the children of that structure to remove all nested `indent` properties, we get your output.

This code is built on that idea:

```js
// Helper function
const deepMap = (fn) => ({children, ...rest}) => ({
  ... fn ({...rest}),
  ... (children ? {children: children .map (deepMap (fn))} : {})
})

// Main function
const extractTree = (text) => 
  text
    .split ('\n')
    .filter ((line) => /\S/ .test (line))
    .map (s => s .match (/^(\s*)(.*)$/) .slice (1))
    .map (([prefix, val]) => ({indent: prefix .length, val}))
    .reduce ((path, node) => {
      const {indent, val} = node
      const parentIdx = path .findIndex (node => node .indent < indent)
      const parent = path [parentIdx]
      parent .children = [... (parent .children || []), node]
      return [node, ... path .slice (parentIdx)]
    }, [{indent: -1, children: []}]) 
    .slice (-1) [0] 
    .children
    .map (deepMap (({indent, ...rest}) => ({...rest})))

// Test data
const text = `  
todo list
  learn js
    hello world
    functions
  
shopping list
  costco
  berries


  mushrooms
procrastination list
`

// Demo
console .log (
  extractTree (text)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The `.filter` call removes any empty lines, and ones with only space characters. 
 The `.split` call and the two `.map` calls convert this santized input into that first intermediate format.  They should be fairly clear, I hope.  (You could add some `tab -> space` conversion here if necessary.)

The `.reduce` call is more complex, maintaining a stack of ancestor nodes, starting with a default one with an indent of `-1`, so it will always be lower than any actual value, finding the immediate parent of our current node on the stack as the first one with an indent lower than its own indent, then appending the current node as a child of that parent, and pushing it onto the stack.

After that, we use `.slice (-1) [0] .children` to get the children of the bottom element of the stack, which should be the nodes we care about.

Finally, we `.map`  over the results, passing the helper function `deepMap` to recurse through each of these objects and apply a function we pass it to remove the now-unnecessary `indent` nodes.  `deepMap` is a useful, fairly generic function, applying the function to the node, and, recursively, to each of its children.

---

This does something I don't often do in my code: it mutates the data along the way.  I haven't come up with any clean way to avoid the mutation.  We don't mutate the original input data -- we're not barbarians! -- but the internal nodes are mutated during the `reduce` call.

If anyone sees a clean way to do this without that sort of mutation, I'd love to hear about it!

Comment: Nice linear approach, Scott. I'm putting it in my vscode to step through it and understand the transformation. This is very clever management of a stack. Does `path.findIndex` work because we parents nodes are _prepended_ to the result? My main concern is `path.findIndex` which will become inefficient as the input grows but I'm still wrapping my head around it...  I'm also wondering if this approach has a better way of dealing with empty lines.

Comment: > _"...without mutation"_ - I show one possible way in my post

Comment: @Thankyou: Yes, by prepending the node, we use the array as a LIFO stack, and rather than popping or pushing values, `findIndex` lets us chop off the irrelevant head.  I think there might be inefficiences in `findIndex` as we tend towards hundreds of thousands of rows, but I'd be surprised if it had those sorts of problems when its smaller.  The bigger problem for performance is probably that I'm doing too *little* mutation.  There's a new array for the stack on every line.  That might lead to a lot of garbage collection.  If empty lines are a problems, I would just filter them out early.

Comment: @Thankyou: I thought you might show up with an interesting solution.  I'll try to look at it this evening.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer but it might help you build your object:

```
var text = `todo list
  learn js
    hello world
  other level
   deeper
shopping list
  costco
procrastination list`;

var paths = []; // this will store our path tree

parseText = () => {
    var lines = text.split("\n");
    var outputObject = {};

    var pathsStack = [];
    var previousSpaces = 0;

    lines.forEach( line => {
      //var line = lines[key];
      var spaces = line.match(/^\s*/)[0].length; // search 

      if (spaces === 0){ // reset path stack
        pathsStack = [line.trim()];
      } else if (spaces > previousSpaces) {
        pathsStack.push(line.trim());
      } else if (spaces === previousSpaces) {
        pathsStack.pop(); // remove last item
        pathsStack.push(line.trim());
      } else if (spaces < previousSpaces) {
        pathsStack.pop(); // remove last two items
        pathsStack.pop(); 
        pathsStack.push(line.trim());
      } 

      previousSpaces = spaces;

      paths.push(pathsStack.join("."));
    });
    console.log(paths);
    /* 
    this will output an array in the following form:
      0: "todo list"
      1: "todo list.learn js"
      2: "todo list.learn js.hello world"
      3: "todo list.other level"
      4: "todo list.other level.deeper"
      5: "shopping list"
      6: "shopping list.costco"
      7: "procrastination list"

    you can now iterate through this array and insert it into your target object.
    */
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**IMO**, the simplest approach is to just do a straight forward `for` loop as the OP originally had it. We just have to use a stack and maintain some references to achieve the goal.

Pros: `O(n)` performance and code read-ability.

Here's my attempt (Details are in the comments):

```js
let input = `item.1
    item.1.1
        item.1.1.1
item.2
    item.2.1
item.3
item.4
    item.4.1
        item.4.1.1
        item.4.1.2
        item.4.1.3
        
    item.4.2
        item.4.2.1
            item.4.2.1.1
                item.4.2.1.1.1

                item.4.2.1.1.2
                item.4.2.1.1.3
            item.4.2.1.2
                item.4.2.1.2.1
            item.4.2.1.3
        item.4.2.2`;

// Updated to use 2 stacks (for spaces and parent items) so that we don't include
// the spaces count in the final result.
const parseList = list => {
    const final = []; // The final result
    const parents = []; // A stack to maintain parent references.
    const spaces = []; // A stack to track parent spaces.
    let parentItem = {
        children: final // Use final reference so initial parent is a proxy to the final result
    };
    let parentSpaces = -1; // Initial space starting at -1 (which can never occur)
    let prevItem;   // The previous list item
    let prevSpaces; // The previous item's spaces

    const lines = String(list).split("\n");
    const lineCount = lines.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        const line = lines[i].trim();
        const currSpaces = lines[i].search(/\S/);

        // Ignore empty lines
        if (line) {
            // Here's the magic!!
            // If the current spaces are more than the previous spaces, then this item should be a child
            // of the previous item. Also account for prevSpaces === -1 for initial iteration
            if (prevSpaces !== -1 && currSpaces > prevSpaces) {
                // Set new parent
                parents.push(parentItem);
                spaces.push(parentSpaces);
                parentItem = prevItem;
                parentSpaces = prevSpaces;
            } else {
                // If item is not a child then pop() the parents until the parent's spaces are less
                // than the current item's spaces
                while (currSpaces <= parentSpaces) {
                    parentItem = parents.pop();
                    parentSpaces = spaces.pop();
                }
            }

            // Create new list item
            const item = {
                val: line
            };

            // Add child
            parentItem.children = parentItem.children || []; // This is so the children property isn't created it no child
            parentItem.children.push(item);

            prevSpaces = currSpaces;
            prevItem = item;
        }
    }

    return final;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(parseList(input), null, 2));
```

---

**Response** to **@Thankyou**'s challenge

Let's compare these 2 functions:

```js
const max0 = (x, y, z) => x > y ? x > z ? x : z : y > z ? y : z;
// variable: 3
// mutations: 0
// variable reassignments: 0
// lines of implementation: 1
```

and

```js
const max1 = (x, y, z) => {
  let max = x;
  if (y > max) max = y;
  if (z > max) max = z;
  return max;
}
// variable: 4
// mutations: 0
// variable reassignments: 2
// lines of implementation: 5
```

By those metrics `max0` would be deemed simpler but would that be the case if you were to ask 100 random developers? These metrics, although objective, doesn't tell the full story (ie: function calls, language features, dependencies, etc...), nor does it define a person's subjective concept of simplicity.

Could I have inlined some things and use a native language features to reduce these metric? Sure! But I didn't. I will admit that seasoned developers will likely prefer your answer for its elegance, craftiness, and "simplicity". But my crude implementation has other benefits and shows yet another way that it can be done while using rudimentary constructs. Ones which even a noobie like myself (and hopefully others less senior than yourself) can pick up readily. There's a reason universities teach `for` loops before recursion. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Nice, but do note the differences between this and the requested output format.  It might not be an issue for the OP, but how would you fix these issues?  The trivial one is the property name of `line` versus `value`.  That's a one-line change.  But there are two more.  Every object has a `children` property, even if it's only an empty array.  Would it be easy to remove these?  And every one also has an extraneous `nbrSpaces` property.  If they are unwanted, how would you remove them?

Comment: I would add that this is not `O(n)`, you have a `for` wrapped around a `while`.

Comment: I challenged your _"simplest, straightforward"_ claim in an edit to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61392976/633183)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks, I was working off the OP's own code and didn't realize the output format was a bit different. But as you've comment, it is a simple change and I've update my sample to match the OP's desired output. Side note, other answers didn't match the output either...just saying ; )

Comment: @Thankyou Although there is a nested `while` loop, given the nature of the problem, it will execute at most `n - 1` times. So worst case is still linear. As for your challenge, I'm absolutely excited that someone exactly spent the time to compare notes. Ultimately "simplest" in this context is subjective, hence my answer started with **IMO**. You definitely got me on code reusability. I don't know if I can subjectively agree with your other points. But it was a good read, and again @Thankyou  <--- See what I did there? : )

Comment: This context is subjective? All of the code points I compared are objective. Fwiw, your revision is [14 variables, 5 mutations, 6 reassignments, 37 lines](https://pastebin.com/qd61n4wg).

Comment: @Thankyou: While I personally agree that the metrics you calculate are some of the most important ones, the choice of which metrics to use has some measure of subjectivity involved. If you compared by number of function calls or number of recursive invocations, the results would be different  To me there are several big advantages of your approach here.  Most importantly, it breaks the work down into a number of bite-sized chunks. Mine would look more like that if I used a library to help make certain parts point-free, and used a pipeline, but it has an irreducible complexity yours avoids.

Comment: I haven't tried to do any non-trivial complexity analysis for many years, so take this with a grain of salt.  The algorithm from tokafew420, while more than linear, looks to my rusty eyes as likely to be `O (n log n)` or less.

Comment: Wow my first SO squabble. I've finally made it!! This is an interesting debate and your challenge is noted. However I don't see the need for your ire as we've just met :( I edited my answer with a response to your challenge and hopefully we can leave it at that. In the end I feel that your answer, my answer, and your challenge will all benefit this community and those in search for something more than just *copy/paste*, so @Thankyou <--- See it did it again : )

Comment: @ScottSauyet Correct me if I'm wrong in my thinking but the inner loop is `O(n)` for the entire execution of `parseList()`. Its function is to traverse up the tree if necessary. For a problem size `n` the max depth is `n` (no matter the arrangement). So technically we're looking at `O(2n)` but that boils down to `O(n)`. I wouldn't have the slightest idea on how to write a proof for this but that's just my thinking.

Comment: @tokafew420 I never intended for a squabble. I appreciate your thoughtful remarks and I agree that I think the whole community benefits from the discussion.

Comment: @tokafew420: The key phrase there is *inner loop*. There's an outer loop that's also got `n` elements.  A first impression is that it might be `O(n * n)`, that is `O(n^2)`. But if we have to unwind `k` elements for the `k`th entry, the next one is only `1` deep, and no subsequent ones can be more than `n - k` deep. I'm curious as to the possibilities, but not to the point of doing the deeper thinking that it seems to entail. I throw my hands up and say it must be approximately `O(n log n)`, with nothing more than the instinct that says it's the most common answer between linear and quadratic.

Comment: @tokafew420: as to the question of complexity, layout and naming are major issues.  This is pretty unreadable too: `const max1 = (x, y, z) => {let m = x; if (y > m) m = y; if (z > m) m = z; return m;}`.  But there are some important points in Thankyou's analysis, and if you haven't seen Rich Hickey's famous talk, [Simple Made Easy](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy/), I'd highly recommend it.