# Convert a list object into another structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, recursion

I have a list, converted into js array. Several rows has a Tab prefixes:

```
var data = [
    "2",
    "    2.1",
    "        2.1.1",
    "    2.2",
    "3",
    "4"
]
```

What I'm trying to do, is to get following structure:

```
var data = [
        "2",
        "2->2.1",
        "2->2.1->2.1.1",
        "2->2.2",
        "3",
        "4"
    ]
```

Tried (Produce wrong result):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            
            var current = data; 
            var length  = data[i].length - data[i].replaceAll("    ", "").length;
            
            if (!length) {
                console.log(current); 
            } else {
                console.log(data[i-1] + '->' + data[i].trim()); 
            }
}
```

**Update (@MustSeeMelons)** - your solution produce wrong results on test data attached below:

[image]

Comment: Correct, updated.

Comment: Do you really need to use tabs for it?  `2.1.1` corresponds to `2->2.1->2.1.1` because it has two dots, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. I'm using tabs as a prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to this.

##### Approach #1:

In case you're allowed to use auxiliary space, create an array that will keep track of the latest level of the rows. It is not based on the separator.

```js
let data = ["2","\t2.1","\t\t2.1.1","\t2.2","3","4"], tab="\t", latest = [];

let output = data.map(x => {
   let noTabs = x.split(tab).length-1;
   latest = [...latest.slice(0, noTabs), x.replaceAll(tab, '')];
   return latest.join('->');
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: an actual tab is `\t` and not "composed of 4 spaces"

Comment: Nice solution, but you are split the number by (.). But the data may not be just numerical. Currently it works for specific data only.

Comment: Check the second solution to see if it's what you asked

Answer (score 2):

**flat to tree**

I solved this problem in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61392976/633183). We can reuse the same functions on your data -

```js
const data = `
2
    2.1
        2.1.1
    2.2
3
4
`
```

```js
// using makeChildren and sanitize from the linked Q&A
console.log(makeChildren(sanitize(data)))
```

```js
[
  {
    "value": "2",
    "children": [
      {
        "value": "2.1",
        "children": [
          {
            "value": "2.1.1",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": "2.2",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "3",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "value": "4",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

**tree to flat**

All that remains now is to convert the tree to flat list of `paths` -

```js
function* paths(t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      for (const child of t)
        yield* paths(child)
      break
    case Object:
      yield [t.value]
      for (const path of paths(t.children))
        yield [t.value, ...path]
      break
  }
}
```

```js
const result =
  Array.from(paths(makeChildren(sanitize(data))), path => path.join("->"))
```

```js
[
  "2",
  "2->2.1",
  "2->2.1->2.1.1",
  "2->2.2",
  "3",
  "4"
]
```

**advantages**

Decomposing the problem into smaller parts makes it easier to solve and yields reusable functions but those are not the only advantages. The intermediate tree representation gives you the ability to make other modifications in the context of the tree that the flat representation does not permit. Additionally, the `paths` function yields arrays of paths segments, allowing the caller to decide which final effect is desired, ie `path.join("->")`, or otherwise.

**demo**

Run the demo below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const sanitize = (str = "") =>
  str.trim().replace(/\n\s*\n/g, "\n")
  
const makeChildren = (str = "") =>
  str === ""
    ? []
    : str.split(/\n(?!\s)/).map(make1)

const make1 = (str = "") => {
  const [ value, children ] = cut(str, "\n")
  return { value, children: makeChildren(outdent(children)) }
}

const cut = (str = "", char = "") => {
  const pos = str.search(char)
  return pos === -1
    ? [ str, "" ]
    : [ str.substr(0, pos), str.substr(pos + 1) ]
}

const outdent = (str = "") => {
  const spaces = Math.max(0, str.search(/\S/))
  const re = new RegExp(`(^|\n)\\s{${spaces}}`, "g")
  return str.replace(re, "$1")
}

function* paths(t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array: for (const child of t) yield* paths(child); break
    case Object: yield [t.value];  for (const path of paths(t.children)) yield [t.value, ...path]; break
  }
}

const data = `\n2\n\t2.1\n\t\n\t2.1.1\n\t2.2\n3\n4`

console.log(
  Array.from(paths(makeChildren(sanitize(data))), path => path.join("->"))
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

**remarks**

`outdent` is generic and works whether you use literal tabs, `\t` `\t\t` `\t\t\t...`, or some number of spaces. What matters is the whitespace is *consistent*. View the [original Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61392976/633183) for more insight on how each part works.

Answer (score 0):

This will almost do what you wish, not sure how you want to group them:

```
const mapped = data.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
  if (idx !== 0) {
    // Get leading digit of current & previous element
    const current = curr.trim()[0];
    const previous = acc[idx - 1].trim()[0];

    // If leading match, aggregate them
    if (current === previous) {
      acc.push(`${acc[idx - 1].trim()}->${curr.trim()}`);
    } else {
      acc.push(curr.trim());
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(curr.trim());
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Don't use `for` loops unless you need to break out of the loop at some point. Transforming arrays usually should be done with the `map` function.
I used `reduce` because this problem required me to access the new, already mapped element.

Comment: Take a look @ updated question, please